# Cannot retrieve value from JSON format

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am working on a React.js app connected with a Java backend. I am receiving a JSON object from the backend but I cannot access its key-value pairs.

[image]

Here is the object that I retrieve. I am passing this data from a Parent to Child component. When I am console logging in the child component I am retrieving the above mentioned object.

I am trying to access its properties this way:

```
props.eventsData[0].description
```

This does not work. How can I access the object`s values?

Comment: You are getting the above response for `props.eventsData`?

Comment: How are you pass the data to the child component? Possible share a simple codesandbox with sample data.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-yalow-brtp4?file=/src/CardItem.js

Comment: codesandbox is incomplete. Could you please update it ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-tree-u6n6b?file=/src/Cards.js it is updated now.